# How to ask user to snap on a vertex of a line element (in the ILocateCommandEvents_Accept handler) of Microstation VBA

Tags: vba, microstation

I know how to write a VBA macro in Microstation that will ask the user to select an element:

```
Sub Create2DCrossLines()
    ' Set error handler
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Let the user select the bank elements himself
    Call CommandState.StartLocate(New clsSelectBanksLCE)

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Call ReportError("Create2dCrossLines")
End Sub
```

`clsSelectBanksLCE` uses `ILocateCommandEvents` for managing that part of the logic. So the user can select a `LineElement` for example and when the `Accept` event is fired it runs an action:

```
Private Sub ILocateCommandEvents_Accept(ByVal Element As Element, _
                                        Point As Point3d, _
                                        ByVal View As View)
```

In my particular case we track selecting element 1 and then element 2 and once both elements are selected it proceeds. This is all fine.

My problem is this: after I accept the first element, and before proceeding to select the next (ie: in the `Accept` handler) I want to get the user to snap on to two vertices of the line element.

I need to know which part of the line element they want to process. I can't work out how to do this. In AutoCAD you can use `GetPoint`.

So I want to ask them to snap on to the first vertex on this line element, then snap onto the end vertex. After this can we move on to select the second element.

## Update

I have just stumbled over this [article](http://www.la-solutions.co.uk/content/CONNECT/MVBA/MVBA-MoveElement.htm). I notice it says:

> Once the user has accepted an element, we should start another class that implements **IPrimitiveCommandEvents** to obtain a target **datapoint**. Finally, compute the offset from the supplied locate datapoint to the target datapoint and move the element.

It seems what I want but I just am not clear on the right order. At the moment I have:

`ILocateCommandEvents_Start` This begins the location process.

`ILocateCommandEvents_LocateFilter`. If the element is a `LineElement`, then it 
assigns `m_Element1` and the second event fired assigns `m_Element2`.

`ILocateCommandEvents_Accept` If both the variables are not `nothing` it runs the main process.

See my dilemma? It sounds like I need to:

- Run one instance of `ILocateCommandEvents` to select one element only.
- Then run one instance of `IPrimitiveCommandEvents` to get the first snap point.
- Then run another instance of `IPrimitiveCommandEvents` to get the second snap point.
- Then run another instance of `ILocateCommandEvents` to get the second element.
- Finally, once the second element is accepted, perform my processing.

That is how I understand I need to do it. Or, can I use my one `ILocateCommandEvents` class that currently gets the user to choose two elements?

Guidance appreciated.

## Update

I got it to work by following the above logic. That [article](http://www.la-solutions.co.uk/content/CONNECT/MVBA/MVBA-MoveElement.htm) really helped. The only issue I have now is that I need to draw a rubber band. But that is a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [article](http://www.la-solutions.co.uk/content/CONNECT/MVBA/MVBA-MoveElement.htm):

> Once the user has accepted an element, we should start another class that implements **IPrimitiveCommandEvents** to obtain a target datapoint. Finally, compute the offset from the supplied locate **datapoint** to the target datapoint and move the element.

The link also provides example code on how to use the `IPrimitiveCommandEvents` event class.